# Как установить фейковый уровень заряда?

Tags: android, root

Андроид 10, рут есть
Не просто поменять значение в индикаторе, а чтобы система не выключалась при 0%

Comment: Энергия из воздуха будет поступать?

Comment: @user7860670 У батареи беды с башкой и и она не разряжает её до конца

Comment: Ох, сомневаюсь что вам тут помогут, а может и помогут...

Как я помню, в старые добрые времена батарею андроида можно было калибровать!, нет это не вмешательства в аппаратную часть) это именно изменение программной части, помню занимался модингом древних 2.6 андроидов.... Не знаю, как сейчас обстоит с андроидом 10. Заряжаешь до 100%, удаляешь data/system/batterystats.bin.

Comment: @DenisKotlyarov Тут проблема не с телефоном, а с контролером в батарее. Он отдаёт слишком мало ёмкости. При достижении 0% после выключения системы телефон работает в тпвр еще около 2-х часов на полной яркости. А я хочу, чтобы он эту энергию отдавал на работу системы.